# Are services created by ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance() disposed automatically by the DI container?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

The [basic .NET Dependency Injection Guidelines docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#disposal-of-services) say:

> The container is responsible for cleanup of types it creates, and calls Dispose on IDisposable instances. Services resolved from the container should never be disposed by the developer. If a type or factory is registered as a singleton, the container disposes the singleton automatically.

I'm not clear on whether objects created by [`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) count as a service "resolved from the container". If I use this method to create an instance which implements `IDisposable` or `IAsyncDisposable`, am I responsible for disposing it myself? `CreateInstance()` definitely *uses* the container to resolve other dependencies of the requested type.

I believe `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance()` is able to create objects whether or not their types or interfaces are registered with the DI container. Does creating an instance of a registered `IDisposable` service, or creating an instance of an unregistered `IDisposable` type, make any difference in terms of who is responsible for disposing the created instance?

Comment: What happens with an instance you get from CreateInstance? Do you register it with the container so other services can resolve that instance? If not, then you're on your own I guess.

Comment: It's impossible for `CreateInstance` to track it for disposal in the container, because it has no knowledge of the expected lifetime of that instance. In other words, it has no idea when to dispose of that instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance()` always creates new instance and you are responsible for its disposing. There is no container registration.

Source code:

[ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/045e55abac82e89e0daaee47bcb8433e0fc9ccbc/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/src/ActivatorUtilities.cs#L164)

[ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/045e55abac82e89e0daaee47bcb8433e0fc9ccbc/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/src/ActivatorUtilities.cs#L788-L800)

Comment: Except of course when such created instance is returned from a delegate that is added to the container using on of the `Add[Lifetime]` methods. But in that case it's still not `CreateInstance` that is tracking it for disposal.